# How can I poll for updates to an item in a list?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Given a list of tasks:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])
```

I want to add a task on user input with `setTasks(...tasks, aNewTask)`, and then update the results of that task asynchronously:

```
while (true) {
  taskStatus = await getTaskStatus()
  setTasks(tasks.map(t => t.id == taskStatus.id ? taskStatus : t))
}
```

which looks logically correct. But it doesn't work; the task is added to the list, then deleted subsequently. `tasks` isn't being updated, so querying it yields the original list, before I called `setTasks` the first time. The best workaround I see while still using the same pattern is to wrap `useState` in a custom hook, and resolve a promise as part of the set-value function, but even then I need `tasks` to be `var` so I can update it locally.

Is there a cleaner way, that still uses the async logic?

Comment: I think you should use redux-saga to handle such cases.

Comment: Doesn't  useEffect with tasks dependency help you? You can do whatever you want in that effect when tasks are chaged.

Comment: Can you make modifications in `getTaskStatus()` to make it an observer pattern?

Comment: You can remove the tasks form the effect dependency when you pass a callback to setTasks: `setTasks(tasks=>tasks.map(t => t.id == taskStatus.id ? taskStatus : t))` This will solve either stale closure or infinitely triggering the effect (effect depends on tasks but will change tasks when it's run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an effect that sets state after an asynchronous action you should check if the component is still mounted before setting that state.

Here is an example that checks before setting state and will exit the infinite loop when component is unmounted. The effect has no dependencies so will only be run after first render. The tasks is not a dependency to the effect because I pass a callback to setTasks.

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React;
//helper to check if component is mounted so you won't
//  try to set state of an unmounted component
//  comes from https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted/blob/master/index.js
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};
//returns current date after waiting for a second
function getTasksStatus() {
  return new Promise(r =>
    setTimeout(() => r(Date.now(), 1000))
  );
}
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(
    Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  );
  //from the helper to check if component is still mounted
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();
  useEffect(() => {
    //babel of Stack overflow is ancient and doesn't know what
    //  to do with async so I create a recursive instead
    function polling() {
      getTasksStatus().then(newTasks => {
        //only do something if component is still mounted
        if (isMounted.current) {
          //pass callback to setTasks so effect doesn't depend on tasks
          setTasks(currentTasks =>
            Math.floor(newTasks / 1000)
          );
          //call recursively
          polling();
        }
      });
    }
    //the async version with "infinite" loop looks like this
    // async function polling() {
    //   //exit loop if component is unmounted
    //   while (isMounted.current) {
    //     const newTasks = await getTasksStatus();
    //     isMounted.current && //make sure component is still mounted
    //       //pass callback to setTasks so effect doesn't depend on tasks
    //       setTasks(currentTasks =>
    //         Math.floor(newTasks / 1000)
    //       );
    //   }
    // }
    polling();
  }, [isMounted]);
  return <div>{tasks}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So this is close I think, but since I'm updating a single value in an array of  values, it needs to use `currentTasks` when creating the new value for the array. I actually didn't know the setter from `useState` allows for a lambda where the current (i.e., updated) value of the data is passed to you. I think that's all there is to fix my issue - just add a param when I'm setting the resulting array after I get the http response :)

Comment: @Rollie That is why I added a comment indicating you can pass a callback to the setter of useState. But then I thought the component may be unmounted at some point and you're stuck with a never ending loop that produces lots of warnings so I decided to add it as an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with doing a `setState` inside a loop is that it will only trigger the thing once. To make it so it will "poll" you can wrap it with a timeout function:

```
let timeout = null; //outside class
...
while (true) {
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    taskStatus = await getTaskStatus()
    setTasks(tasks.map(t => t.id == taskStatus.id ? taskStatus : t))
  }, 1000);
}
```

the `1000` is the number of millisecond to run the set task/poll.

make sure you clear the timeout on unmount like so:

```
useEffect(() => () => clearTimeout(timeout)));
```

This is so it doesn't poll if the component is no longer active

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not true; under the covers, the `await` will return control to the platform code, where changes are batched and eventually applied.

Comment: Oh my bad, you have to incluide the getTaskStatus inside so it will have an updated value once the task is triggered - i edited my answer